# Send flood message in Ad hoc network

Tags: c++, networking, adhoc

I'm writing a c++ program that will run on some form of Linux (likely debian-based) that needs to connect to an ad hoc network then send a flood message. I can accomplish the connection itself, but I'm at a loss on how to send a flood message. I could write my own protocol for it, since all machines on the network will be running my software, but I'd like to have it work a layer down. I've looked around on the internet and I can't find any api's for sending a flood message. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is a flood message?

Comment: surely you need to write your own protocol

Comment: A flood message is a message sent to all nodes of an ad hoc network. I know there's some way to do it on the network layer, but I don't know how.